# What's the name of the song played in season 3 episode 14 at about 21:15-21:57?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What's the name of the song played in season 3 episode 14 at about 21:15-21:57 when Deku saves All Might from the falling rock?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's name and it's called Jet Set Run